# jquery validation: change appearance

Tags: jquery, validation

It's my validation script:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            frmDate: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            frmAmount: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            frmReceipt: {
                number: true
            }
        },
        errorElement: "span",
        wrapper: "span",  // a wrapper around the error message
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            offset = element.offset();
            error.insertAfter(element)
            error.addClass('form-error-message uk-alert uk-alert-danger');  // add a class to the wrapper

        },
        onsubmit: false
    });


});
```

It wraps the element if its data is not valid, I want to change this. What I want to do is just add a class to the elements that only makes a red border around them (assume this class is called `my-error-class`) and maybe add a tooltip that is default `jquery validation` plugin messages, and then remove the class when user fixed input. 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all invalid inputs are marked with class `error`, as well as the messages themselves.  So you can do that just with css:

```
input.error {
    color:red;
}
```